# GIF maker for 18.04 without losing quality

Tags: 18.04, software-recommendation, gimp, image-processing, gif

I am looking for a GUI tool like GIMP to create animated GIFs from PNGs. I tried GIMP 2.10. The quality of GIF is low in it. Perhaps to reduce the size of GIF, but there are burrs on the side of the GIF (due to low image quality).

For example, here the edge outline has burrs, base image was clean:
[image]

I tried a few online convertors and Photoscape in Windows. Online tools had even less quality and Photoscape gave almost the same quality as GIMP.

I know there is another question which talks about ImageMagik. But kindly avoid suggesting CLI tools. Hoping to find a suitable tool.

Comment: Image compression is a setting in GIMP. You can change it. The number of GIMP-like applications that are free is very limited, obviously...and they generally use the same underlying libraries, so your uniform lack of success is not a surprise. There are several online tutorials about various strategies to use when shrinking images to guide toward a final product you will like.

Comment: @user535733 Can you tell me how to keep the GIF as the same quality as the base images in GIMP ? Where can I change the image compression settings for GIF ? Thanks.

Comment: It's impossible to keep the 'same' quality when throwing away some image data. While I have played with image compression, not on this particular machine so answer will be delayed...or somebody with GIMP ready at hand is welcome to beat me to it.

Comment: Please take your time. When I tried, the image quality of GIF was close to poor. I hope you have see JoyPixel's animated smileys. Their GIF quality is as good as what we get from SVG. I wonder which tool they use.

Comment: Question: Are you [reducing each image](https://www.designbrooklyn.com/resources/blog/view/Optimizing-Images-for-the-Web-using-GIMP-2013-11-06/)? Or are you [optimizing the final animated GIF](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/35366/)? Have you tried both ways?

Comment: I am exporting from Inkscape with decent quality. I am looking for quality that reduced size. Haven't scaled or optimised in any way. I want the reverse, I don't mind the size ( can't be huge though ). I just need to avoid the depreciation while making GIF through GIMP.

Comment: Are you saying that the GIF, upon initial import into GIMP, is poor quality? Try saving the imported GIF with no changes, and then open in an image viewer. Also open the GIF exported from Inkscape in the same image viewer. Compare the two.

Comment: I use good quality exported images from Inkscape. All I need is that GIF frames keep the same quality than deteriorate.

Comment: Hmmmm: When I import a GIF into GIMP, then save it, it's the same quality. The two GIFs, side-by-side, are identical. My GIFs do not deteriorate. I do not understand what you might be doing differently.

Comment: Please see this GIF https://imgur.com/6h24rzq . The edge outline has burrs. Base image was clean.

Comment: You can't have clean edges on a GIF that work on all backgrounds, because such edges require partial opacity and the GIF format doesn't support it.